# Reading an integer from a file using FileInputStream

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to read an integer I have saved to a file in my android internal storage. Using FileInputStream's read method, it only returns an int as a byte. I'm wondering if there is a way to read the integer I have saved to the file?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide your code

Comment: Did you save it as text, as a big-endian int, or as a little-endian int?

Comment: I saved it by using a FileOutputStream to write an int value to the file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FileInputStream allows you to read the file byte by byte. The integer you saved is four bytes long. You can read it by either using the FileInputStream to read the four bytes yourself and use them to construct your int, or use a higher level utility, such as [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html):

```
public static int readInt(FileInputStream in) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in);
    return scanner.nextInt();
}
```

Comment: `nextInt()` will try to read characters spelling out a number as a string and convert them to an int; it will not read four bytes and treat them as a 32-bit int. Actually, after re-reading the question, that *may* be what OP wants. It's unclear.

Answer (score 2):

Try using readInt() method. 
This method gives you int value

Working example
http://www.java-examples.com/read-int-file-using-datainputstream